# Win.JS.UI.Animation slideToggle

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi I'm looking for the animation in metro style app of doing the same as slideToggle of jquery, there is one like this or can I create something like this in a custom animation?

Comment: What is the UI activity that you intend to use a slideToggle animation for? If you are adding items to a list, then a better animation would be addToList. (Or if you really want slideToggle, then just call slideToggle. You can use jQuery in your metro-style app.)